# Null Pointer on Hibernate's createQuery()

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm struggling to get to the bottom of a null pointer exception that happens when I try to run a HQL query with createQuery().

The code to run the query is pretty simple. Originally I had a named query that I was calling, but just to make things more simple and eliminate any complications I'm doing this (springwildlife is the package and Species is the class/entity):

```
Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT s FROM springwildlife.Species s");
```

(BTW: I've also tried it with and without the package name in there. And I've also tried doing a simpler "FROM springwildlife.Species" query)

I've created an XML mapping (species.hbm.xml) like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="springwildlife.Species" table="species">
      <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="id" >
          <generator class="native">
              <param name="sequence">species_id_seq</param>
          </generator>

  </id>

  <!-- in the actual file I have one these for each item I want to be mapped -->

  <property name="propertyFromClass" type="java.lang.String">
   <column name="sql_table_column_name" />
  </property>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

In my hibernate.cfg.xml file I pull in the mapping like so:

My class/entity looks like this:

```
package springwildlife;

public class Species
{
    // properties here

    public Species()
    {
    }

    // sets, gets, etc.

}
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what is happening? I've spent a lot of time trying to track it down and I'm stymied.

(I'm not sure it is relevant, but just in case, I'm using Resin as my server and IntelliJ as my IDE)

This is the stack trace (line 68 in SpeciesFactory.java is the call to createQuery):

```
[11-06-02 11:19:26.726] {http://*:8080-2} org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:119)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:96)
    at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletFilterChain.doFilter(ServletFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:156)
    at com.caucho.server.webapp.AccessLogFilterChain.doFilter(AccessLogFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletInvocation.service(ServletInvocation.java:287)
    at com.caucho.server.http.HttpRequest.handleRequest(HttpRequest.java:792)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.dispatchRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:730)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:689)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequestsImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:669)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequests(TcpSocketLink.java:617)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.AcceptTask.doTask(AcceptTask.java:104)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionReadTask.runThread(ConnectionReadTask.java:98)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionReadTask.run(ConnectionReadTask.java:81)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.AcceptTask.run(AcceptTask.java:67)
    at com.caucho.env.thread.ResinThread.runTasks(ResinThread.java:164)
    at com.caucho.env.thread.ResinThread.run(ResinThread.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at springwildlife.SpeciesFactory.getSpeciesLister(SpeciesFactory.java:68)
    at springwildlife.LifelistController.handleRequestInternal(LifelistController.java:26)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: It might help to also post the first few lines of the stack trace if it doesn't just point to that line of code.

Comment: Since you're using annotations to mark entity classes, why are you using `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

Comment: Matt, it was an afterthought to see what happens..... When I originally stumbled on this problem the annotations were not there. I've removed them in my post for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Michael and Steve, I've posted the stacktrace.

Comment: well, what happens at `springwildlife.SpeciesFactory.getSpeciesLister(SpeciesFactory.java:68)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `NullPointerException` is thrown at the line with `createQuery()`, the only possible cause is that `session` is `null`.

Comment: Not completely true, as Gregor B. Rosenauer said, there may be an error in HQL.

Comment: It could be HQL syntax problem.

Answer (score 17):

In my case the Session object was valid but I still got the `NullPointerException`.
Turned out to be an error in my HQL (`SELECT TCompany FROM TCompany c...` instead of `SELECT c FROM TCompany c...`).
So if the Session is valid, you might check your HQL...